# How can I resolve this SVN problem?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

On my local machine I have svn set up. I have a theme folder in which I have two themes A and B. I created B by making a copy of A and removing the svn directories. I then modified B theme. The problem comes when I commit A or B. I get a message saying it needs to be updated, but it updates with the other themes data. What steps should I take to fix this? How can I prevent this from happening again? Thanks.

EDIT: It is possible I forgot to delete one of the svn folders (there are quite a few). If I delete from subversion these 2 themes and then readd them, do you think it will fix it?

Comment: Before doing anything make a copy of your theme folder to a different directory out of SVN control first... just in case :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you remove *all* SVN directories in the copy, including from sub-directories? If you did, you should be able to `Add` the B folder.

Generally, instead of copying folders, use SVN's own `export` function (Tortoise will give you an option in the context menu if you right-click and drag the folder to a new location). It makes sure the copy is 100% clean from any remaining SVN data.

Comment: Where is the export function? I don't see it when I right click on the folder.

Comment: @Allison right-click a folder that is under version control, hold the button, and drag it to a different window

Answer (score 1):

It seems like if you actually did remove the svn folder from B, then you would have had to add the B folder as new files.  I think you need to repeat the process, being careful to only copy the source files from A into a new B folder, without any of the SVN baggage.  Then add the B folder as new stuff.